# Vue3 - Communication between two components children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3

With Vue 3, I've the following component structure:
[image: diagram]

As you can see, ChildA is able to communicate with ChildB and ChildB must be able to change its state accordingly.

With Vue 2, I was able to send an event in `ChildA`:

```
this.$root.$emit('new-message', data)
```

And then handle it in `ChildB`:

```
this.$root.$on('new-message', (data) => {
   this.state = data
})
```

But since Vue 3, `$on`, `$once` and `$off` have been removed. How can I achieve this communication in Vue 3 ?

Comment: Why not create a store, to keep track of the data between components?

Comment: [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) - amongst it's many many useful vue composition utilities, has [useEventBus](https://vueuse.org/core/useEventBus/) - which gives you `on`, `once`, `off`, `emit` and `reset`  - and will clean up any listeners on unmount

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data attribute, in this example just called `data`, then you can use [`reactive`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) to create a simple store, which can then be imported by both sibling components (in this example Component A and B)

```js
// store.js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
  data: 'New Message',
  setData(something) {
    this.data = something;
  },
})
```

```html
<!-- ComponentA.vue -->
<script>
import { store } from './store.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      store
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>From A: {{ store.data }}</template>
```

And

```html
<!-- ComponentB.vue -->
<script>
import { store } from './store.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      store
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // If you need to trigger an event on change, then:
    'store.data'(newData, oldData) {
      console.log('Data Changed', { newData, oldData });
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>From B: {{ store.data }}</template>
```

When the state in the store updates, the changes will be reflected in all child components that use it. This should be simpler than the Vue 2 `$emit` pattern, as you don't need to manage tracing events through the component tree.

Comment: I believe *tracing events through the component tree* would not be required with `this.$root.[$emit | $on | $off]` etc

Comment: I'm confused ... the question asks for how to send from A to B - but your answer reads store.data in both A and B ... and nothing ever sets data to anything

Comment: This solution shares a reactive variable instead of providing a direct event listener. The sibling component can implement the actions on the change of the data through a watch or by other means. While this doesn't provide a way to listen to the other component's event, it is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: The syntax is similar to state in React, so is probably more familiar to React devs, but way too complicated IMO for this use case.